# Unsupported Version of Play billing

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, in-app-billing

i am using react-native-billing library with version 3.0.0. I am facing an issue i.e, when we roll out the APK for production, after upload we are getting this error message :

"We've detected this app uses an unsupported version of Play billing. Please upgrade to Billing Library version 3 or newer to publish this app"

PROBLEM:-
I have manually added the following line in

android/app/build.gradle ->implementation project(':react-native-billing')

android/build.gradle -> minSdkVersion = 16,compileSdkVersion = 28,targetSdkVersion = 30

with these following details, the application is working fine but google refuses to upload our build with this error:-

"We've detected this app uses an unsupported version of Play billing. Please upgrade to Billing Library version 3 or newer to publish this app"

SOLUTION WE TRIED:-
added the following line in android/app/build.gradle
implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing:3.0.0"

using Android API 30

With these changes, the build was successfully uploaded but we are not getting a product list from "In-app products".
And after adding this line in debugging mode the application was crashing on this line.
InAppBilling.open();
We are importing InAppBilling from the "react-native-billing" library.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue - it looks like the plugin react-native-billing was built off of another plugin (https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3) when Billing Library version 2 was the standard. Plugin android-inapp-billing-v3 has since updated to Billing Library 3 but react-native-billing has not implemented the required changes to match up. I've been able to force react-native-billing to pull the newer version of android-inapp-billing-v3 and am attempting to update the plugin manually (so far unsuccessfully) but if better heads want to give it a crack:

in 
~\node_modules\react-native-billing\android\build.gradle

update:

dependencies {
        ...
        implementation "com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:${safeExtGet('anjlabIABVersion', **'2.0.3'**)}"
 
   }

then follow this migration guide:
https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3/blob/master/UPGRADING.md

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31234979)